# Como saber se o primeiro caracter de uma string está em maiúsculo?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Preciso saber se o primeiro caractere de uma `string` está em maiúsculo e não deixar o programa seguir.

Como fazer?

```
Console.Write("Digite o nome do " + i + "º rei: " );
            kings[i] = Console.ReadLine();

        while ((kings[i].Length < 1 ||  kings[i].Length > 20 ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O nome está inválido");
            Console.Write("Digite novamente");
            kings[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma *string* é uma coleção de caracteres. Aí você deve pegar o primeiro e usar o método [`IsUpper()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.char.isupper?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para retornar se é maiúsculo. Para evitar a negação poderia usar se é minúsculo com [`IsLower()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.char.tolower?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), assim: `char.IsLower(king[0])`. Em alguns casos pode ser mais interessante a opção com invariância de cultura ([`ToUpperInvariant()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.char.toupperinvariant?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write("Digite o nome do rei: " );
        while (true) {
            var king = ReadLine();
            if (king.Length > 0 && king.Length < 21 && char.IsUpper(king[0])) break;
            WriteLine("O nome está inválido\nDigite novamente");    
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7TmKEC). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MpEZw0). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ValidatingFirstChar.cs).

No ficaria algo assim:

```
char.IsUpper(king[i][0])
```

Comment: O seu não está funcionando

Comment: Acredito que você fez algo errado então, coloquei *link* na resposta mostrando que funciona. A única coisa que tinha de errado é que precisava inverter a condição e dar a saída.

Comment: Dei ctrl c, ctrl v no meu projeto, ele não está validando a primeira letra maiuscula

Comment: Acho que você precisa analisar o que está fazendo. Programar não é copiar e colar, é entender o que está acontecendo com o código. Eu coloquei duas fontes diferentes mostrando que funciona. Obviamente que eu tive que mudar o código para poder compilar, afinal você não colocou todo o código, se tivesse colocado todo ele eu poderia ajudar mais. Eu não posso reescrever todo seu código, até porque teria que advinhar o que é, para poder colocar algo que você possa colar e compilar sem alterações.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma simples de verificar se o primeiro caractere é maiúsculo (ou não) é:

```
char.IsUpper(kings[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma variável booleana que informa se o primeiro caractere é maiúsculo, e fazer seu IF com ele.

```
bool estaMaisculo = "Teste".ToCharArray()[0].ToString() == "Teste".ToCharArray()[0].ToString().ToUpper();
```

No lugar de "teste", você pode colocar sua variável.

Answer (score 0):

Não testei esse código mas pode ser que te ajude

`kings[0].CompareTo(kings[0].ToString().ToUpper());`